# What is the difference between a term query and a match one?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have documents with string fields which are not analyzed (enforced by a mapping or set globally). I am trying to understand what is the practical difference between

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {"match": {"hostname": "hello"}},
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
{
    "query": {
        "term": {
            "hostname": "hello"
        }
    }
}
```

I saw in the documentation for [term queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html) that there is a difference when the strings are analyzed (which is not my case). **Is there a reason to use `term` vs `match`?**

Comment: `term` vs `match` right?

Comment: Yes, sorry - i meant `match` of course.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In a `term` query, the searched term (i.e. `hello`) is not analyzed and is matched exactly as is against the terms present in the inverted index.

In a `match` query, the searched term (i.e. `hello`) is analyzed first and then matched against the terms present in the inverted index.

In your case, since `hostname` is `not_analyzed` in your mapping, your first choice should be to use a `term` query since it makes no sense to analyze a term at search time for searching the same term that hasn't been analyzed in the first place at indexing time.

Comment: This is quite helpful and to the point. Is there any place in the documentation of Elasticsearch where this is mentioned?

Comment: @akki Actually, when using a [`match` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html), ES will be smart enough to do what I described above.

Comment: @akki  The official docs mentions this info here: [Term-Based Versus Full-Text](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/term-vs-full-text.html)