# How to query list of elements field in Elastic search

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, filter

This is my result source.

> { "_source": { "Name": "Madagascar", "Genre": [ "Fiction" ],
>      "AgeGroup": "11-13", "description": "Storks leave behind .",
>      "duration": 3, "is_series":false}

I need to apply `is_series = False & Genre=['Fiction']`. I tried this query, but it is not working.  Please help.

```
{"query":{"bool":{"filter":{"terms":{"Genre":["Action"],"is_series":False}}}}}
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the query you're looking for:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "match": {
            "Genre": "Action"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "is_series": false
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: But this {"query": {"bool": {"filter": [{"terms": {"Genre": ["Action"]}}]}}} returns Zero hits.          {'took': 2, 'timed_out': False, '_shards': {'total': 5, 'successful': 5, 'skipped': 0, 'failed': 0}, 'hits': {'total': 0, 'max_score': None, 'hits': []}}

Comment: I've updated my query, you're better off using `match` instead of `terms`

Comment: @Val , what you suggested `match` instead of `terms` ?

Comment: @AmitKhandelwal here is the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40124317/what-is-the-difference-between-a-term-query-and-a-match-one/40124408#40124408

Comment: @Val ,I knew the difference b/w `match` and `terms`, I just missed that here `Action` was passed in query while, it would be indexed as `action`. Hence `match` is a better choice. I think it would be good to add this in the answer.