# elasticsearch matching exact word

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm working with the [Enron-dataset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enron_Corpus) in elasticsearch. 
The mail bodies are split into paragraphs which are stored as nested documents. But that is besides the point, I just want you to make sense of the query itself.
I wanted to verify that everything's works as expected, so I looked for an uncommon word in the corpus and wanted to query for it. My intention was to check, whether the total hit value would be correct. I was confused, because I always got a value of 10000 which was far to high.
I chose the word `electrons`, which occurs some times in the corpus. However, my query also matches `electronic` which is contained in practically every mail in the corpus (I exaggerate).
Here's my query:

```
curl -X GET "localhost:9200/enron/_search?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "_source": {
    "includes": [ "*" ],
    "excludes": [ "body" ]
  },
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "body",
      "inner_hits": {       

      },
      "query": {
        "constant_score" : {
            "filter": {
                "match": {
                    "body.content" : "electrons" 
                }
            }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
'
```

Don't mind all the stuff around it. It looks like this, because I'm only interested in the paragraphs containing the word `electrons`. This already is a test query for finding out what's going on under the hood. It returns the document, and only the inner document (body) with the matched term.
I suspected that the `match` filter was the culprit. So I changed the query in the filter to `match_phrase`. However, that didn't change anything.

How can I match the word `electrons` in a text field (inside a nested document) without matching `electronic` and other similar words?

Edit:
The suggested [Term query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html) is not recommended for Text fields. Asides, it wrongfully returns 0 hits:

```
{
  "_source": {
    "includes": [ "*" ],
    "excludes": [ "body" ]
  },
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "body",
      "inner_hits": {       

      },
      "query": {
        "constant_score" : {
            "filter": {
                "term": {
                    "body.content" : "electrons" 
                }
            }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
'
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 0,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  }
}
```

Edit2:
I guess, I have found the error. The analyzer was set to `snowball` for the text field. No wonder it didn't find an exact match for the term.
I'm reindexing.

Edit3:
It was my fault. It works with the standard analyzer. ES also finds the correct Documents using `match`, by the way.

Comment: what is the type of the field body.content in schema?

Comment: Use term instead of match for exact word.

Comment: The type is Text.

Comment: can you try with type as a keyword?

Answer (score 0):

Use term filter instead of match for exact word, see the explanation below

[What is the difference between a term query and a match one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40124317/what-is-the-difference-between-a-term-query-and-a-match-one?rq=1)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention it, but I already tried the Term query. It returns 0 hits. It is also not recommended for text fields according to the documentation.